# Python recommendation engine

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

Is there a recommendation engine for python similar to [Java Taste](http://taste.sourceforge.net/old.html)?

Comment: Looks very specific, Just wrap it up and use it from Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found much that runs natively in python, but someone created python wrappers for SUGGEST, which looks like a solid program.

[SUGGEST overview](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/suggest/overview)

[python wrappers](http://code.google.com/p/pysuggest/)

Since python is still fairly slow when compared to C or Java, using wrappers will probably improve performance.

Comment: have you used SUGGEST? On what basis are you saying it's solid?