# Tag/Keyword based recommendation

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am wondering what algorithm would be clever to use for a tag driven e-commerce enviroment:

- Each item has several tags. IE:

  **Item name:** "Metallica - Black Album CD", **Tags:** "metallica", "black-album", "rock", "music"
- Each user has several tags and friends(other users) bound to
  them. IE:

  **Username:** "testguy", **Interests:** "python", "rock", "metal", "computer-science"
  **Friends:** "testguy2", "testguy3"

I need to generate recommendations to such users by checking their interest tags and generating recommendations in a sophisticated way.

Ideas:

- A Hybrid recommendation algorithm can be used as each user has friends.(mixture of collaborative + context based recommendations).
- Maybe using user tags, similar users (peers) can be found to generate recommendations.
- Maybe directly matching tags between users and items via tags.

Any suggestion is welcome. Any python based library is also welcome as I will be doing this experimental engine on python language.

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704845/python-recommendation-engine

Comment: Much better question, though.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad / tool rec.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) Weight your tags.

Tags fall into several groups of interest:

- My tags that none of my friends share
- Tags a number of my friends share, but I don't
- My tags that are shared by a number of my friends.

(sometimes you may want to consider friend-of-a-friend tags too, but in my experience the effort hasn't been worth it. YMMV.)

Identify all tags that the person and/or the person's friends have in interests, and attach a weight to the tags for this individual. One simple possible formula for tag weight is

```
(tag_is_in_my_list) * 2 + (friends_with_tag)/(number_of_friends)
```

Note the magic number 2, which makes your own opinion worth twice as much as that of all of your friends put together. Feel free to tweak :-)

2) Weight your items

For each item that has any of the tags in your list, just add up all of the weighted values of the tags. A higher value = more interest.

3) Apply a threshold.

The simplest way is to show the user the top *n* results.

More sophisticated systems also apply anti-tags (i.e. topics of non-interest) and do many other things, but I have found this simple formula effective and quick.

Comment: Thanks alot for your kind answer! I am a bit confused about the formula: What does exactly tag_is_in_my_list mean? if it some kind of binary as 1 or 0 ? Cheers

Comment: any example/sample implementation on this

Answer (score 5):

If you can, track down a copy of O'Reilly's Programming Collective Intelligence, by Toby Segaran. There's a model solution in it for exactly this problem (with a whole bunch of really, really good other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to product recommendation engines, such as Amazon's well publicized site. These use a learning algorithm called [association rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), which basically build a conditional probability of user X buying product Y based on common features Z between the user and product. A lot of open source toolkits implement association rules, such as [Orange](http://www.ailab.si/orange/doc/ofb/assoc.htm) and [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python Semantic module](http://legacy.drools.codehaus.org/Python+Semantic+Module) for Drools to specify your rules in python scripting language. You can accomplish this easily using Drools. It is a terrific rules engine that we used to solve several recommendation engines.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Restricted Boltzmann Machine. Gets around the problem of similar but not identical tags quite neatly.

Comment: Could you flesh this answer out a little more, like HOME you would use an RBM?